# Change brightness Vaio FZ

Tags: 11.10, brightness, vaio

I can't change the brightness on my Vaio VGN-FZ340E.  There isn't even a slider on the screens window. The only way I've found to do it is to use smartdimmer throught the command line, however this is pretty inconvenient.  any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Relevant bug report: [No Screen Backlight Control; Notebooks with Nvidia Geforce8/Geforce9/Quadro series graphics](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/95444)

Answer (score 2):

(SOLVED) Please see the link

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1004568&page=3

I have Sony Vaio VGN FZ340E and after long search I found the solution in the following link

http://doube.org/karmic-vaio

and now its working perfect without any problem I've only changed the (the SPIC to SNC) for both files

```
sony-brightness-up
sony-brightness-down
Shown expression
```

for sony-brightness-up file

```
event=sony/hotkey SPIC 00000001 00000011
```

I used the following expression

```
event=sony/hotkey SNC 00000001 00000011
```

for sony-brightness-down file

```
event=sony/hotkey SPIC 00000001 00000010
```

I used the following expression

```
event=sony/hotkey SNC 00000001 00000010
```

Backlight

Backlight support for Vaios is now incorporated in nvclock
Make sure you have nvclock installed for basic backlight control, and until HAL has been updated you have to specify the hotkey event manually.

```
sudo apt-get install nvclock
nvclock -S 100
nvclock -S 15
nvclock -S +10
```

Enable the "brighter" hotkey:

```
sudo gedit /etc/acpi/events/sony-brightness-up
```

put this text into it:

```
event=sony/hotkey SNC 00000001 00000011
action=/usr/bin/nvclock -S +10
```

And the "dimmer" hotkey:

```
sudo gedit /etc/acpi/events/sony-brightness-down
```

put this text into it:

```
event=sony/hotkey SNC 00000001 00000010
action=/usr/bin/nvclock -S -10
```

Make the scripts executable

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/events/sony-brightness-*
```

Restart acpid

```
sudo /etc/init.d/acpid restart
```

If you have a different model, you might have different keys controlling your backlight. To check the event ID, run

```
acpi_listen
```

Answer (score 0):

Other Solution Which is better visit this link :

[Brightness not working after installing NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76081/brightness-not-working-after-installing-nvidia-drive)

Just Download the following file 
https://github.com/downloads/guillaumezin/nvidiabl/nvidiabl-dkms_0.72_all.deb

Then run the following in the terminal

```
echo "nvidiabl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```