# Backlight Issue - Samsung RV509 Notebook

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, brightness, samsung, backlight

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 today on my Samsung RV509 Notebook (Nvidia Geforce 315M) and the backlight brightness controls don't work on it.

I did some digging around the web and found the samsung tools voria [repository](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa) and installed Samsung-backlight package from there. This didn't help though.

I see that the Nvidia drivers are in use. Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I just figured out that I can decrease brightness from the nvidia X server setting panel directly. Ubuntu is still unable to directly decrease the brightness from system settings though.

Comment: Ok, I got a bit confused between brightness and backlight. The nvidia setting decreases the brightness of the images,vidoes ect, so they start looking dull and undefined. What I'm looking for reducing backlight intensity.

Comment: **possible duplicate:** http://askubuntu.com/q/76081/43660

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

And change to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save and close the file. Then update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and check.

This did the trick for me on a Samsung NP300 notebook. The brightness keys in the keyboard were not working before this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I made this change. Now when I unplug the power the backlight decreases automatically. Bad part, the hot keys (Fn keys) do not work anymore. I have not way left to change the backlight manually. I do not care much about the Fn keys but I want a way to change backlight manually whenever I want.

Comment: Thanks @Tom , your trick works nicely for my Samsung RV509 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, And I have no problem with Fn keys, I can control brightness with those keys.

Comment: This answer saved me again, on the same Samsung RV509 (which is now 10+ years old) I installed Xubuntu 22.04 and faced the same problem. And this solution worked again, but this time Fn keys are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Add

```
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

to the `“Device”` section so it looks somewhat like this:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier  "Default Device"
Option  "NoLogo"    "True"
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Then restart the X server.

Comment: You may want to edit your post to include information about how to restart the X server. Also, please note that, as discussed in comments to this question, backlight intensity and brightness are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use Ubuntu 11.10. And install all the available drivers from the Voria repo. Make sure you have nvidia_bl installed which is required to correctly manage brightness.