# unable to change brightness settings in sony vaio e series laptop

Tags: brightness, sony

I am using Sony Vaio E Series VPCEH25EN laptop.
I installed ubuntu 12.04 64 bit version and I couldn't change my brightness level.

Always it is showing max brightness,

I tried to change by using `echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` command.

When I run the above cmd it showing output as 0 but there is no change in brightness level. please help out how to change brightness levels.

Comment: Please do not post your question as an *answer* to similar questions!

Comment: take a look at this post. I have a NVIDIA chip to and had to edit my xorg configuration to get Brightness Control
http://askubuntu.com/questions/76081/brightness-not-working-after-installing-nvidia-driver

Answer (score 4):

Your system has nvida chips. So please install driver from `Addtional Drivers` (press <kbd>Super</kbd> / <kbd>Win</kbd>, and search for it). Reboot and see if it solves the problem.

If above not working try following (but don't uninstall the driver)

execute `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Change this line

`GRUB_CMLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to something like below

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Execute `sudo update-grub` and reboot . See if brightness keys are working.

It is still possible ubuntu won't remember your brightness settings. So you have to change brightness each time.

Please let us know the result as many sony users are facing this problem.

---

Update: This is for setting brightness manually.

Try following for path shown by `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` and replace accordingly.

Get the maximum brightness:

`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`

Try a lower value to set the brightness, say output is 2048 so I will try with half of it

`echo 1024| sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

**If this works**,  make this happen in each login automatically by doing the following

`sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

Enter this line just before `exit 0`. It should look like

```
echo YOUR_VALUE_HERE > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
exit 0
```

Also you can try with [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) [image: Install xdotool]

Comment: i tried both but still the same problem.no change at all

Comment: i tried that...first i tried  changing the value lik the way u said by using echo | but there is no change at all...the display brightness is same at the max level

Comment: did you installed the driver? see this user is reporting it worked correctly. What is o/p of `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` ?

Comment: when it is in max_brightness range its displaying as 15..even though i change the value its changing to 8,9 etc but the screen brightness is still at high state...

Answer (score 0):

This link helps me to solve this issue:
https://askubuntu.com/a/266618/186926

Problem solved just by editing /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.
If this file is not there in your system, then create it and copy paste its content as mentioned in above link.

Cheers!

Jasleen

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Here at Ask Ubuntu, we help moderate the site by flagging questions as duplicates to others. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to [flag posts](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).