# How can I controll Brightness in Sony Vaio SVE151A11W?

Tags: brightness, vaio, sony

**Disclaimer First:**

- I have gone thorugh these following threads here and followed all of
  their advice but none of them worked
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/74376/brightness-control-problem-on-sony-vaio-with-nvidia-gt-320m
- [unable to change brightness settings in sony vaio e series laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154557/unable-to-change-brightness-settings-in-sony-vaio-e-series-laptop)
- [Brightness doesn't change on Sony laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186002/brightness-doesnt-change-on-sony-laptop)

**Now the Problem**

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 (64bit) in this Sony Vaio laptop. After vanilla isntallation the brightness keys are working and I can see the brightness indictaor going up and down but it isn't having *any* effect on the real brightness of the device.

I have installed additional drivers too but that didn't solve the problem.
I can't seem to be able to change the brightness.

Anyone knows how I can fix this?

Comment: This might help. I also had the same problem with my sony vaio. I found the solution here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/236616/brightness-control-keys-on-sony-vaio-not-working-on-12-10

Comment: @imankurpatel000 the link you provided just points me to another link where I have the same set of instructions(posted here) which doesn't help at all.

Comment: Sorry the link was wrong. Here is the original: http://askubuntu.com/questions/247145/brightness-controls-are-not-working-in-sony-vaio-with-amd-radeon-hd-7650/247570#247570

Comment: I ahve tried that solution. Sadly it didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the issue.
Hence posting for the help of others coming to this post using search.

None of the techniques shown above worked for me.
But goto the AMD's website (I have Radeon 7670 HD) and download their linux BETA driver which will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

the only way to change brightness is to use this command

sudo su

echo 150 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

all other solution does not work at the moment.
this is not my work around. i dont remember where i got this but it works and hats off to the person who gave this workaround :)

Using Ubuntu 13.10 64Bit Wubi on Lenovo Z570

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same answer fits on multiple questions, flag the latest one as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying /etc/default/grub changing the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Then run `sudo update-grub`

If it doesn't work try changing the same line to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"` and update-grub again.

Comment: I tried doing both of them.
And None of them worked.

The only thing they did was to disable the brightness hotkeys in my keyboard.
I've tried editing the [code]/etc/X11/xorg.conf[/code] file but in my case it's a blank file (I'm uisng ATI card)

Comment: [This](http://vaioubuntu.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/finally-a-brightness-how-to-for-vaio-fw-series/) might help.

Comment: Isn't that for FW series?