# Sony Vaio-Brightness Settings not Changing

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, brightness, sony, backlight

I've searched for this problem but I cant find a straight answer.

If I go into `/etc/class/backlight`, there's nothing there. Could someone help?

I have the Nvidia Driver installed, and the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys aren't changing the brightness.

Answer (score 3):

First give a try to [obacklight](http://dev.osource.se/docs/obacklight/).

Earlier it solved may problems with sony laptops. **Most preferable solution**. It is based on [nvidabl](https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl). You need to install nvidiabl first. Installation instruction is available on the page.

---

If the above is not working, revert back all changes. Uninstall nvidiabl & remove obacklight script from `/etc/init.d`. Then follow below instructions:

1. Execute `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Change this line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   to something like the below:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
   ```
3. Execute `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

See if brightness keys are working.

It is still possible ubuntu won't remember your brightness settings. So you have to change brightness each time.

---

This is for setting the brightness manually after doing the above steps.

Try the following for the paths shown by the command `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` and replace accordingly. An example path will be like `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`.

1. For the path(s), get the maximum brightness:

   ```
   cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
   ```
2. Try a lower value to set the brightness. Let's say if the output is `16`, try half the number:

`echo 8 | sudo tee  /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

**If this works**,  make this happen in each login automatically by doing the following:

1. `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`
2. Enter this line just before `exit 0`. It should look like

   echo YOUR_VALUE_HERE > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
   exit 0

---

**Another fix if the above fails**:

1. Run nVidia X Server settings which you can find in the Application menu.
2. Select X Server Display configuration and chose the `save to x configuration file` option. This will build file `xorg.conf`. Close Nvidia X Server settings.
3. `sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` in terminal.
4. Find this section:

   ```
   Section "Device"
   Identifier     "Device0"
   Driver         "nvidia"
   VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
   BoardName      "GeForce GT 540M"
   EndSection
   ```

   And change it to something like this:

   ```
   Section "Device"
   Identifier     "Device0"
   Driver         "nvidia"
   VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
   BoardName      "GeForce GT 540M"
   Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
   EndSection
   ```
5. Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands:

```
sudo -s    
echo n > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

`n` is the desired brightness value. For example, if I want to set my brightness to `5`, I’d run this:

```
sudo -s    
echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

This solution works on my Sony Vaio laptop.

Edit:

Try the answer to this question: [Brightness is reset to Maximum on every Restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart)