# Brightness control in Ubuntu 14.04 on Sony Vaio?

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, brightness, vaio, sony

I recently installed **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** on my Sony Vaio [nVidia **GeForce 410M**/PCIe/SSE2]. Earlier I had 12.04 installed on it, then I edited the **xorg.conf** file to control brightness using the function keys. But now the file is empty and even if i created it like last time it ain't working. I tried the xbacklight too, it didn't worked.

Please Help....

Thanks

**EDIT:** Ubuntu Installed is **64bit** version.

Comment: Try second solution from http://askubuntu.com/a/266618/285763 (that one that starts with "Execute gksu gedit /etc/default/grub")

Comment: @artis Sorry sir, That didn't work either.

Comment: @HiteshBhatt did my answer work for you?

Comment: @Korkel No Sir, It ended up even more screwed. The display went blank, didn't even showed in failsafe.

Answer (score 5):

I have a Sony VPCEH notebook, I had the same problem.

I tried this solution that worked for me:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221452#6

Briefly:

> With root privileges, create the file
>   /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20nvidia.conf with the following content
>
> ```
> Section "Device"
>     Identifier     "Device0"
>     Driver         "nvidia"
>     VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
>     BoardName      "GeForce 410M"
>     Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
> EndSection
> ```
>
> Log out and back in again to test.

And it gently adds: "If something goes wrong, simply delete that file and reboot to recover the system."

But I didn't need that addition. After logout and login the brightness control started to work again.

I hope it helps you too...

Comment: worked for me...

Comment: Works here with Macbook Pro, Ubuntu 15.04 and GForce 9400M. I changed the BoardName to "GeForce 9400M".

Comment: works with me VPCEH28FN with nVidia 410M

Answer (score 2):

edit note: don't change anything related to intel files especially `usr/share/x11/20-intel`
because yours is **NVIDIA** and it broke my Ubuntu. I couldn't open Ubuntu anymore, so I removed 20-intel in safe mode from the console.

**JUST do this to recreate:**
this will  **recreate etc/X11/xorgconf**
 **be root** then  execute this on **terminal**

```
nvidia-xconfig
```

lastly be sure that you are pasting `enablebrightness` in right section which is **section "device"**

for  **nvidia** and **ubuntu 14.04** *x64*
check this post ... it solved mine.

[ubuntu 14.04 fn brightness nvidia not working samsung r540](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558980/ubuntu-14-04-fn-brightness-nvidia-not-working-samsung-r540)

**HOW I SOLVED IT**

in terminal

```
# nvidia-xconfig
```

this creates /etc/X11/xorg.conf . edit it.

```
# sudo su  // become root
# gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

find **Section "device"** in text.
it should look like this on the right side:

```
from this                        TO   this     

Section "Device"                  | Section "Device"
 Identifier "Device0"             |   Identifier  "Device0"
 Driver     "nvidia"              |   Driver      "nvidia"
 VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"  |   VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"
                                  |   Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection                        | EndSection
```

save changes (ctrl+S).
log out. log in.

we are done!!
now <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Up/Down</kbd>  is adjusting the brightness.

this post will make your **fn+up ,down** keys work

Comment: Awesome this is really well written and worked perfectly on Lenovo also

Comment: Worked for my Sony Vaio like a charm. Thanks a lot @blackholeearth0_gmail!

Comment: im looking this post at jan 2016 . and im really glad that at least Two people get benefit from this. thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and make this file if it doesn't exist:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

We need to edit that file, so enter the following in a terminal:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Then add the following in the file and save it:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection
```

Log out and in again, and it must work.

Comment: Be careful I tried this an it caused me not to be able to boot my computer anymore and had to run safe-mode and remount the drive and delete it completely

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python code to alter the screen brightness [BrightnessControl](https://github.com/arunvelsriram/BrightnessControl).

Before running check if the follwing file exists `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`
The content of this file is an integer indicating the current brightness.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the file does not exists.

Comment: Locate the file which stores the current screen brightness and modify the code to make it work.

Comment: there is a link to another location as "acpi_video0" in /sys/class/backlight . It has files as "actual_brightness", "brightness" and "max_brightness", can you suggest me a script which allows me to change the brightness in "brightness" through the hotkeys? I need to change the brightness much often and can't stick to a single value.