# Fn keys to adjust brightness not working on Samsung R540 with Ubuntu 14.04 and in India GT330M

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, brightness

Ubuntu 14.04 on Samsung R540 with nvidia gt330m

When I press Fn + up or Fn + down it doesn't change the monitor's brightness, but in the top-right corner of the screen the brightness indicator moves left and right.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HOW I SOLVED IT**

**note:** if you havent installed  nvidia driver. Install it before you continue this.

in terminal

```
# nvidia-xconfig
```

this creates /etc/X11/xorg.conf . edit it.

```
# sudo su  // become root
# gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

find **Section "device"** in text. add this line

```
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

so it shold look like it on the rightside

```
from this                        TO   this
```

```
Section "Device"                  | Section "Device"
 Identifier "Device0"             |   Identifier  "Device0"
 Driver     "nvidia"              |   Driver      "nvidia"
 VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"  |   VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"
                                  |   Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection                        | EndSection
```

save changes (ctrl+S). 
log out. log in.

we are done!!
now Fn + Up,Down  is adjusting the brightness.

Comment: It works for Dell L702X as well.