# Display brightness setting not working in sony vaio SVE151117F

Tags: 12.10, brightness, vaio, sony

I have sony vaio  SVE151117F, ubuntu 12.10.I used to see brightness animation upon pressing Fn+F6,F5 but not actual brightness of screen.
I have tried to implement as said in  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2086359
but now I cant even see the brightness level animation.There is no change in brightness level of screen as usual.

I tried below links too , but still problem persists.
[unable to change brightness settings in sony vaio e series laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154557/unable-to-change-brightness-settings-in-sony-vaio-e-series-laptop)
http://vaioubuntu.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/finally-a-brightness-how-to-for-vaio-fw-series/

Comment: Have a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/303088/screen-brightness-reduction-software/303093#303093).

Answer (score 1):

Go to the link below and download the driver by entering the commands posted their. Check the list of supported cards (probably listed their if not don't get panic give it a try. Personally mine is not their but that commands  worked for me)

http://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu.html

After installing reboot your laptop. then try this:

1. Create the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/15-nvidia.conf`:

   ```
   gksu gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/15-nvidia.conf
   ```
2. Copy/paste the following content:

   ```
    Section "Device"
     Identifier              "Device0"
     Driver                  "nvidia"
     VendorName              "NVIDIA Corporation"
     Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
    EndSection
   ```
3. Save the file and reboot

Answer (score 0):

dont mess that directory usr share i messed there and count open get and gui so i had to go in safe mode then remove that usr/share/x11/xx-vendor.conf

then do these.

**HOW I SOLVED IT**

**note:** if you havent installed  nvidia driver. Install it before you continue this.

in terminal

```
# nvidia-xconfig
```

this creates /etc/X11/xorg.conf . edit it.

```
# sudo su  // become root
# gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

find **Section "device"** in text.
it shold look like it on the rightside

```
from this                        TO   this
```

```
Section "Device"                  | Section "Device"
 Identifier "Device0"             |   Identifier  "Device0"
 Driver     "nvidia"              |   Driver      "nvidia"
 VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"  |   VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"
                                  |   Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection                        | EndSection
```

save changes (ctrl+S). 
log out. log in.

we are done!!
now Fn + Up,Down  is adjusting the brightness.