# 15.10 Dell Vostro 3700 display brightness fn+key change problem

Tags: dell, brightness, 15.10, backlight

I have 15.10 default install, no any changes to `/etc/default/grub`. Now when I press `Fn + arrowUp/Down` I can see display brightness change notification. Moreover, `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/*` seem to reflect my pressings and notifiaction's bar length. So, everything looks good, but display's brightness does not change at all.

When I try to put `aspm_pcie=force`, `acpi_osi=linux`, `acpi_osi=vendor`, `acpi_brightness=vendor` or some combination of theese --- nothing improves (however I can get things worse: values in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/*` stop to reflect my pressings).

There are other solution which says to put into `xorg.conf` (`Device` section) the line:

```
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

But where should I try to put this line in 15.10?

Is there any other solution so far?

Comment: Is there anything other then acpi_video0 in /sys/class/backlight/? Do also check with acpi_brightness=vendor. `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` is for Nvidia's proprietary river. Does Dell Vostro 3700 have Nvidia graphics? What does it have?

Comment: @mikewhatever, yes, there is `nv_backlight`, too. And yes, I did a check with `acpi_brightness=vendor`, it didn't make any difference. Yes, my Vostro has GeForce GT 330M, but I am not sure which driver does it use. Thank you.

Comment: @mikewhatever, `*_brightness` values in `/sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight` do not reflect my pressings (the are always the same).

Comment: I don't know the scale (0-10, or 0-100), but what happens if you change the value in /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness? Use `echo X` > suso tee /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness, where X is the value. Does the screen brightness change?

Comment: @mikewhatever, yes, it does!

Comment: Then try [this solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/192090/20054). Hope it works.

Comment: @mikewhatever, I have no `xorg.conf`, just `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` with files, no one of which contains `Device` section. Shall I create new file? Where can I read about its content?

Comment: xorg.conf is not there by default. The procedure from my previous comment will create it, just paste the second block of text, then hit ctrl-o to and then ctrl-x to exit.

Comment: @mikewhatever, yes, sorry. So, I have had (and have specified) `nouveau` video driver and nothing helped. Now everything works after `apt-get install nvidia-current` driver. With "clean" `/etc/default/grub`. With `xorg.conf` you've pointed me. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of bug that I figured out recently, I don't know if is the same problem.

The button of backlight change when pressed, but it didn't affect the backlight in fact. I tried installing xbacklight and using xrandr to set the backlight and nothing.

Finally, I tried go in BIOS and change with the same button of keyboard, and(I don't know why), it works!! When I came back to ubuntu, the problem was solved.