# Cannot set brightness with nvidia acpi_video0

Tags: drivers, nvidia, brightness, backlight

I cannot change the brightness of my HP EliteBook 8760w. When I press the brightness keys, ubuntu shoes the meter going down and up, but the screen brightness does not change.

I am using nvidia drivers 367.57 for the Quadro 3000M.

```
user@laptop:~$ ls /sys/class/backlight/
acpi_video0
user@laptop:~$ cat /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness 
20
user@laptop:~$ cat /sys/class/backlight/*/max_brightness 
20
user@laptop:~$ sudo su -c "echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness"
user@laptop:~$ cat /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness 
5
```

Is there anything else I could try to change the brightness?

I tried changing `/etc/default/grub` to add additional parameters to `acpi_backlight`. The following happens:

```
(not defining)  only acpi_video0 exists and brightness does not work
video           only acpi_video0 exists and brightness does not work
vendor          no folder in /sys/class/backlight
native          no folder in /sys/class/backlight
```

Comment: Edit `/etc/default/grub` , add the parameter `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` save the file, run `sudo update-grub` and restart. Here are the references https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight.

Comment: When I add that option, there is no folder in /sys/cclass/backlight at all!

Comment: Try one of the other parameters which are listed in the wiki of archlinux in section "Kernel command-line options". If you say "screen" do you men a external monitor or the display of your laptop?

Comment: when i define `acpi_backlight=vendor` it behaves exactly like without defining. when defining it as `vendor` or `native` the `acpi_video0` folder is missing completely. i am speaking of the built-in laptop monitor. I know the brightness worked years ago... on some ubuntu dist.

Comment: Try the solution from user:Dabor in this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162317/screen-brightness-not-working) but use a parameter where the acpi_video0 folder is not missing. What I don't understand that you said one comment before that the parameter `vendor` gives you no `acpi_video0` folder as well.

Comment: Ah sorry! My last comment is wrong. I cannot modify it anymore. Please see my update on the question!

Answer (score 0):

Worked on my Ubuntu 18.04.03:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

And then restart