# Cannot adjust brightness after installing bumblebee on Dell XPS 15

Tags: grub2, nvidia, dell, brightness, bumblebee

I followed [this guide](https://gist.github.com/whizzzkid/37c0d365f1c7aa555885d102ec61c048) to install bumblebee on my Dell XPS 15 9560 running Ubuntu 17.04 in an attempt to fix the fan-always-on problem. This fixed issue with the fan and the power draw, but now I can't adjust the screen brightness.

When I followed the guide my screen was set to minimum brightness, and now it is stuck that way. The brightness function keys bring up and adjust the brightness bar icon and appear to be working, but the screen brightness does not adjust.

When I boot the screen starts out bright, but then during the boot sequence it dims and stays that way. If I boot into Windows 10 I can adjust the brightness normally.

Changing `acpi_backlight=none` to `acpi_backlight=vendor` on the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub`, running `update-grub` and rebooting has no effect. If I change the entire line from the one suggested in the linked bumblebee install guide to the one suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162317/screen-brightness-not-working) then my system does not boot at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May not be a universal solution, but try this:

```
sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness < /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
```

If you are using the Intel graphics card rather than the Nvidia one:

```
sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness < /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness
```

Alternately, try replacing N with various small numbers (1 - 7 work for me but that is probably hardware specific) in the following:

```
sudo echo N | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Comment: I don't have an `acpi_video0` directory, but I have `intel_backlight` and `dell_backlight` directories. `brightness` and `max_brightness` in `dell_backlight` both contain `15` and `brightness` and `max_brightness` in `intel_backlight` are `75` and `1500` respectively.  Using my brightness function keys changes the value in `dell_backlight/brightness` but does not affect the actual screen brightness, but setting `intel_backlight/brightness` to 1500 worked!

Comment: Good. Sharp of you to poke around and figure out how to adapt that. And good of you to post the details. It will help somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding `acpi_backlight=none` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` string in `/etc/default/grub`, running `sudo update-grub2` and rebooting one more time and this solved my problem. The brightness keys now correctly control my screen brightness. I don't know why this didn't work  on the first try.