# Brightness adjustment not working on Lenovo Y540

Tags: nvidia, lenovo, brightness

So, after installing the drivers for NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, the brightness adjustment is no longer working.

I installed the drivers through: Software & Updates -> Additional drivers -> Using Nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-430 (proprietary, tested)

I can change the value through Fn keys, as well as through the slider, but it does nothing, the screen stays at it's brightest setting.

I've tried various solutions with xorg.conf file I've found online, but nothing seems to work. As a matter of fact, some of the proposed solutions caused the desktop environment not to load.

Ubuntu version: 18.04.3

Anyone has an idea about what could I do to make this thing work?

PS: I'm new to Linux, so please tell if I should provide additional data.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the driver? You shouldn't need to install any extra drivers for your system to work. The open source drivers may be slower for some video games, but they tend to be more reliable and better supported.

Comment: I did want to play some Dota 2, but without NVIDIA drivers it was unplayable.

Comment: Nvidia doesn't make it easy to change the backlight, but it looks like it is possible. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162317/screen-brightness-not-working

Comment: I have the same machine and I had the same problem with all Linux distributions and I was able to solve the problem when I applied this solution https://askubuntu.com/a/1247820/1483352

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

In the BIOS settings, change the Display Adaptor from "Discreet" to "Switchable".