# Brightness control does not work on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660 Ti

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 20.04, brightness, nvidia-geforce

Got proprietary Nvidia drivers installed by Ubuntu itself, graphic card is recognized well by the system yet brightness control does not work when adjusted by either `FN` + `F5/6` shortcut or by dragging brightness slider manually (keyboard shortcut triggers slider move as well, so it's heard by the system).

However: `xrandr | grep " connected" | cut -f1 -d " "` produces single output `DP-2` and `xrandr --output DP-2 --brightness 0.7` **does change the brightness**.

Googled a lot, tried various options, neither works to me. What can I do to make it work when dragging the slider as well?

Comment: Do you by any chance have `acpi=off` or `noacpi` in your grub boot parameters, which would have the effect of disabling your FN+function key controls?

Comment: Nope. Config is good and all the FNs are working.

Comment: What does `ls /sys/class/backlight` reveal? On a laptop the hardware brightness is what FN keys control. Using `xrandr` is software control primarily used for external monitors not built in laptop displays.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix acpi_video0. What does that mean?

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov See if this helps: [nvidia backlight brightness problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935585/nvidia-backlight-brightness-problem)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, finally - after trying lots and lots of options - following helped me:
At the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` folder find file related to your `nvidia` and append following section:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "nvidia"
    VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName "<your graphic card as it named in your system>"
    Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

You can find the name of your graphic by searching for "system" in your Ubuntu. In my case it is `GeForce GTX 1660 Ti` so in abovementioned configuration file it gonna be `BoardName "GeForce GTX 1660 Ti"` - enclosed in doublequotes.

Save and reboot.

Comment: Thank you! That one worked for me. Btw it worked both with and without the BoardName line for me.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Sereja Bogolubov: IS this a Laptop or Desktop?

Comment: @stephanmg laptop

Comment: I see, for regular monitors one can use the OSD panel of the monitor.

Comment: This didn't work for me, and it stopped my graphical interface from starting. After removing the contents above using a non-graphical tty, everything returned to normal (but I still cannot adjust brightness).

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `nvidia-settings`
2. Select `X Server Display Configuration`
3. Click `Save to X Configuration File` (don't click `Save` on opened dialog)
4. Click `Show preview...`
5. Copy `Section "Device" ... EndSection` (maybe you will need to copy `Monitor` and `Screen` sections)
6. Create file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-settings.conf` and paste copied text in it, add to `Device` section `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"`, save file
7. Add to file `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`

   ```
   nvidia
   nvidia-drm
   nvidia-modeset
   ```
8. Run `sudo update-initramfs -u`
9. Restart

If you played with file `/etc/default/grub` than try to remove all `acpi...` settings from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`

Description about steps 7 and 8 is [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/problem-driver-nvidia-455-45-01-on-linux-mint-20-4-6-7/165402)