# No screen brightness slider on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, screen, brightness

Since I installed Ubuntu 22.04, I can't change my screen brightness as there is no slider nor such configs under settings > power. I have no idea what to do.

Already tried to edit grub `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` as in [22.04 jammy shows no brightness sliders under Settings > Power](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405073/22-04-jammy-shows-no-brightness-sliders-under-settings-power) but without any success.

**Edit**:
Worth noting that this slider existed in previous versions of ubuntu in this same laptop (not sure about the version, I've been using 22.04 for quite a while now)

I am using a `acer NITRO 5 AN515-55-59MT` laptop, graphic card `GeForce GTX 1650 TI`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using a laptop? There is no brightness slider in a desktop. In case you are using a laptop, please edit the question to add more information about your hardware.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thanks for your help. Yes, it is a laptop. I added more context (brightness slider worked in previous versions of ubuntu) and some info about my hardware. Do you think there is any relevant extra piece of information I should add?

Comment: No, it seems fine.

Comment: Are you running X or Wayland on your laptop?

Answer (score 0):

find the configuration file related to your nvidia in

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

or

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

Add the below lines at the end of the file and save the file.

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Device0"
Driver "nvidia"
VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Save and reboot.

related:

1. https://askubuntu.com/a/1247820/1698042
2. https://www.debugpoint.com/2-ways-fix-laptop-brightness-problem-ubuntu-linux/