# Recent LCD trouble with 12.04 on 2010 Macbook Air 11 (3,1)

Tags: 12.04, screen, macbook-air

I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 on my Macbook Air 3,1 (11", late 2010 model) and it's been working well, after applying the post-installation patches found on the wiki.

Yesterday (July 24, 2012), after doing an apt-get dist-upgrade, I noticed a glitch with the LCD screen: there is a vertical row of colored pixels that moves from top to bottom, with a marquee-like effect.

I do not think this is a hardware problem, since it does not appear when I boot the computer into MacOS.

The glitch is about 2 mm from the right edge of the screen, so it is not too noticeable (there's usually a scroll bar there), but I still would like to make it disappear.

I did a brief Google search for this problem but haven't found anything yet. Can you suggest how I can investigate and hopefully fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got exactly the same issue here on the MBA 2010 late 11' thus it might be model-specific. It appeared after the last update as you described.

after playing around a bit ... here is what worked for me.

I installed the nvidia-current drivers from the softwar center...
After a reboot X was started with the nvidia drivers and the problem was gone. BUT ... the brightness controls were gone too...

Adding the line

> Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
>   in the Section "Device" of /etc/X11/xorg.conf
>   solved that issue.

See:
[Brightness not working after installing NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76081/brightness-not-working-after-installing-nvidia-driver)
and
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1973581
for more information.

Comment: After installing the nvidia-current drivers, I noticed the "blue tint" Flash bug affecting Youtube videos. I fixed it as indicated here: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue]