# MacBook air 3.1 ubuntu 12.04 won't suspend when closing lid, after installing nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, power-management, suspend, macbook-air

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my MacBook air I had a small graphic problem described here: [Recent LCD trouble with 12.04 on 2010 Macbook Air 11 (3,1)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168183/recent-lcd-trouble-with-12-04-on-2010-macbook-air-11-3-1). So I followed the answer and installed the latest Nvidia driver, but now my air won't suspend when closing lid, but it does work if I suspend manually.

Answer (score 1):

I use XFCE, and here's how I fixed the problem: in settings / power manager, associate "suspend" with "closing the lid" for both AC and battery. It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I read in the link ( https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/bugs#TOC-Hibernate-and-suspend-don-t-always-work-well:-they-make-some-computers-malfunction-or-even-enter-a-coma ) that it's a known issue. The author of the page reckons that "Suspend" be turned off. I am not sure whether a fix is available for this known issue.