# Brightness change freezes Ubuntu with Noveau and Nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, display, brightness, freeze, crash

Both Nvidia and Noveau were working fine before my bios update and now they both crash when I change the brightness. Integrated still works fine with brightness and I've tried several Nvidia drivers with no change. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I figured it out and it brightness adjustments works better now then before my bios update

Here's my fix for my NVIDIA NVS 5400m

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

edited `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

make sure to save and then run `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

then do this [Brightness not working after installing NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76081/brightness-not-working-after-installing-nvidia-driver)