# Ubuntu gets stuck at boot screen (freeze, not black) after attempting brightness fix for NVIDIA card

Tags: nvidia, xorg, brightness, macbook-pro

I tried editing /etc/X11/xorg.conf as detailed here: [Brightness not working after installing NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76081/brightness-not-working-after-installing-nvidia-driver)

My Ubuntu MATE installation on my MacBook Pro Mid-2010 13" now gets stuck at the "UbuntuMATE" boot screen. It just freezes there.

My graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce 320M.

Comment: Can you get to a tty? ctrl+alt+F1

Comment: @Pabi nope... just stays where it is

Comment: Can you boot into singleusermode using grub? How to: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4027/how-do-i-prevent-grub-from-using-starting-any-graphical-ui

Comment: @Pabi Would Ubuntu's Recovery Mode do the job?

Comment: Yes you can enter a root shell from there and revert the changes you made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grub to enter a root shell:
Press <kbd>e</kbd> when in grub and edit the line looking something like:
`linux   /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda4 ro quiet splash` to
`linux   /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda4 ro single`.

Alternatively you can use ubuntu recovery and launch a root shell from there.

Then just revert the changes you made to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and reboot.