# Screen Brightness Ubuntu with nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, brightness

So far, I've tried this solution to my problem:

- [Brightness not working after installing NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76081/brightness-not-working-after-installing-nvidia-driver)

Actually, I don't want to create a global `x.org` file, I want to create:

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-brightness.conf
```

How do I get the driver, vendor name, and board name? Somehow it did not work given the expected parameters.

Edit: I think the parameters in the file are proper:

```
[   102.527] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```